# Package countrycode and regex

Tags: r, regex, country

The R-package "countrycode" contains a data frame (countrycode_data) which also includes a variable called "country.name.en.regex". This variable contains regex patterns that I would like to use in order to create a new column which is either TRUE or FALSE depending on whether the country name or a variation thereof occurs in certain columns, see below for the example.

```
AB <- c('CHINAS PARTY CONGRESS','JAPAN-US RELATIONS','JAPAN TRIES TO')
TI <- c('AMERICAN FOREIGN POLICY', 'CHINESE ATTEMPTS TO', 'BRITAIN HAS TEA')
AU <- c('AUTHOR 1', 'AUTHOR 2','AUTHOR 3')
M  <- data.frame(AB,TI,AU)
M$Japan<- !!rowSums(sapply(M[c(1:3)], grepl, pattern ='JAPAN'))
```

[image]

The regular expression for Japan is of course very simple, however, there are more complicated cases. For instance,

```
> M$Czech_Republic<- !!rowSums(sapply(M[c(3, 7:9)], grepl, pattern ="^(?=.*REP).*CZECH|CZECHIA|BOHEMIA"))
```

In that case, I do get the following error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  invalid regular expression '^(?=.*REP).*CZECH|CZECHIA|BOHEMIA', reason 'Invalid regexp'
>
```

I have now tested all regular expressions provided and realized that those that do not work tend to contain

^(?=.* or ^(?!.*

I have also noticed that for instance word boundaries are not escaped with two backlashes (i.e. \B in the original instead of \B). Is there an easy solution that I am not aware of? Or another alternative approach? Here a few complete examples of regular expressions which return errors:

```
M$China<- !!rowSums(sapply(M[c(3, 7:9)], grepl, pattern ="^(?!.*\\BMAC)(?!.*\\BHONG)(?!.*\\BTAI)(?!.*\\BREP).*CHINA|^(?=.*PEO)(?=.*REP).*CHINA"))
M$United_States_of_America<- !!rowSums(sapply(M[c(3, 7:9)], grepl, pattern ="UNITED.?STATES\\B(?!.*ISLANDS)|\\BU\.?S\.?A\.?\\B|^\S*U\.?S\.?\\B(?!.*ISLANDS)"))
M$Republic_of_Korea<- !!rowSums(sapply(M[c(3, 7:9)], grepl, pattern ="^(?!.*D.*P.*R)(?!.*DEMOCRAT)(?!.*PEOPLE)(?!.*NORTH).*\\BKOREA(?!.*D.*P.*R)"))
```

Thanks! 
SCW

Comment: To make the lookahead patterns work add `perl=TRUE`. Also, the Czech regex that you want should look like `"^(?=.*REP).*(?:CZECH(?:IA)?|BOHEMIA)"`

Comment: Thanks, Wiktor. Perl did not occur to me, but it seems to have done the trick. Why did you have to change the Czech regex?

Comment: Just force of habit. I thought the `^(?=.*REP).*` referred to all the alternatives in `CZECH|CZECHIA|BOHEMIA`

Answer (score 2):

The `(?=.*REP)` construct is a positive lookahead and is not supported by the default base R regex engine (TRE). To use them, you need to use `perl=TRUE` so that PCRE regex engine was used to handle the pattern.

However, note that `^(?=.*REP).*CZECH|CZECHIA|BOHEMIA` can be re-written to be used with TRE regex engine:

```
REP.*CZECH|CZECH.*REP|CZECHIA|BOHEMIA
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If you have more than 1 positive lookahead, such an approach might prove tedious, and it is in fact more inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should be able to do this much easier just using the `countrycode` package as intended...

```r
AB <- c('CHINAS PARTY CONGRESS','JAPAN-US RELATIONS','JAPAN TRIES TO')
TI <- c('AMERICAN FOREIGN POLICY', 'CHINESE ATTEMPTS TO', 'BRITAIN HAS TEA')
AU <- c('AUTHOR 1', 'AUTHOR 2','AUTHOR 3')
M  <- data.frame(AB,TI,AU)

library(countrycode)

M$Japan <- apply(M[1:3], 1, function(x) "JPN" %in% countrycode(x, "country.name", "iso3c", warn = FALSE))
M$China <- apply(M[1:3], 1, function(x) "CHN" %in% countrycode(x, "country.name", "iso3c", warn = FALSE))
M$UnitedStates <- apply(M[1:3], 1, function(x) "USA" %in% countrycode(x, "country.name", "iso3c", warn = FALSE))
M$UnitedKingdom <- apply(M[1:3], 1, function(x) "GBR" %in% countrycode(x, "country.name", "iso3c", warn = FALSE))
M$Czechia <- apply(M[1:3], 1, function(x) "CZE" %in% countrycode(x, "country.name", "iso3c", warn = FALSE))
M$Korea <- apply(M[1:3], 1, function(x) "KOR" %in% countrycode(x, "country.name", "iso3c", warn = FALSE))
```

or doing them all in one go like...

```r
countries <- c("JPN", "CHN", "USA", "GBR", "CZE", "KOR")
M <- cbind(M, 
      sapply(countries, function(iso3c) 
        apply(M[1:3], 1, function(x) 
          iso3c %in% countrycode(x, "country.name", "iso3c", warn = FALSE))))
```